# Как закрыть доступ к папке не авторизованным пользователям

Tags: node.js, express

Добрый день. Начинаю только осваивать эту технологию и некоторые простые вещи мне не понятны пока =) Хотелось бы узнать как закрыть доступ ко всем файлам не авторизованному администратору)

Имею такой код

```
app.use('/', express.static('build/client/'));
app.use('/admin', express.static('build/admin/'));
```

И что-то вроде проверки

```
app.get('/admin/**', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.login_admin) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/build/admin/admin.html');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

Возможно ли всё это сделать как-то поэлегантнее и проще?)

Answer (score 1):

Куда уж проще? Ваш код и так очень простой. Но вот элегантнее сделать, конечно же, можно.

То, что вы написали, называется "фильтр авторизации". Но почему он посылает файл? Задача фильтра авторизации - только проверить доступ. Вместо отправки файла вам стоило бы вызвать `next()`, позволив отправить файл обработчику `express.static`.

Comment: А разве не надо тут ошибку 403 обустроить?

Comment: Зависит от логики работы авторизации. Сейчас у вас есть всего два состояния: "пользователь авторизован как админ" и "пользователь не авторизован как админ". В такой схеме ошибке 403 взяться неоткуда.

Comment: Он посылает файл потому, что я хочу чтобы по адресу /admin открывался index.html. А так как он открывается по умолчанию, то проверка не происходит вообще, единственный выход, который я нашёл, это открывать другой файл, admin.html в моём случае))

Comment: Проверка не происходит просто потому что адрес `/admin` не попадает под шаблон `/admin/**`.

Comment: Я уже пробовал /admin и ничего не изменилось

Comment: Вопрос решил, просто расположил app.use('/admin', express.static('build/admin/')); ниже проверки